# Menu cost lookup and summary in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I prepare meals and am trying to figure out how to use Excel to summarize what customers owe me based on the dishes they have ordered.

Right now I use dishes with names like *"chicken", "beef", "surfTurf", "tilapia", "wings"*, all with different prices.  So, for example, I was thinking that I could associate a price with the dish "beef", and whenever it sees that word it would substitute that value and sum up the associated values for each customer based on their list of dishes ordered.

As you see in the picture below, I have *customer name* in column A and in subsequent columns starting with column D is a list of the dishes they have ordered (the quantity of dishes varies).

I want Excel to give me a **total of what they owe me** based on what they have ordered.  In C4 and C5, I have manually inputted the total for those two customers.  I want to be able let Excel automatically calculate how much they owe me.  How can I accomplish that?

[image: CLICK HERE FOR EXAMPLE PIC]

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you want to do and what you're starting with.  Can you provide some mock data or a screenshot of what you want it to do (fake the result but indicate where the values should have come from in the calculations)?

Comment: done added picture.

Comment: you need a helper column for each column completed with a dish to convert it into a value then sum the results.

Comment: The description isn't clear.  You have repeated dish names for each person and you describe wanting to sum up a value for the row based on encountering a specific dish once.  Is the problem that you want to associate a price with each dish, and then convert the dish names to their values and add up the values?  (cont'd)

Comment: If so, create a "duplicate" sheet. However, instead of the dish names, it would contain a lookup of the cost for the dish name listed in the same position on the original sheet. You can pre-populate the maximum possible number of cost cells, using a null ("") value if the original cell is blank. Then sum the entire range on each row and the result will include only the cells that contribute a value. The sum can be on the original sheet, or on the lookup sheet and then reference that cell on the original sheet.  In another location, maybe a third sheet, have a lookup table of dishes and prices.

Comment: What I hoped to achieve is similar what Im using the Countif formula to tell me how many "chicken" dish I have on the spread by telling me how many times the word is used. So lets say I type Chicken Rice, I would want it to know Chicken dish value is $7 so in a separate cell next to their name it would display $7, And if I type Salmon Rice Next to Chicken Rice(so this person has two meals so far) it will Calculate the original $7 plus now $12 for salmon for a total of $19.

Comment: So at the end of day I dont need to go person by person on the sheet with a calculator adding up what amount Im going ask for. I would hope theres a way it can do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

As *Solar Mike* said in his comment, you are going to need helper columns.  Something like the following would work:

[image]

The **Plate 1** and **Plate 2** columns contain the text description of the customer's order. The **Plate 1 Cost** and **Plate 2 Cost** contain the value of each item ordered.  The values in the **Cost** columns comes from a lookup formula that is pointed at a list of plates and their values (columns H & I).  Showing the individual formulas looks like this:

[image]

The formula I used follows this basic pattern `=IF(C2="",0,VLOOKUP(C2,$H$2:$I$6,2,FALSE))`.  You can look up the details of the `IF` and `VLOOKUP` statements, but suffice it to say that the `IF` statement needs to check for blank plates or the `VLOOKUP` will return `#N/A` which would cause any math using that column to fail.  The `VLOOKUP` range (`$H$2:$I$6`) needs to include the `$` symbols or when you copy it to other rows or columns it will fail to work properly, and the final `FALSE` statement is required or it will just return the closest value, even if it isn't in the list (which would make your totals incorrect).

You will need to do a helper column for every plate column you use, but the **Cost** columns and the table of plates and costs can all be hidden or put on another sheet (or even another workbook altogether).  Because `VLOOKUP` requires an exact match to work, you should look into **Data Validation** and use the list from your plates table.  That is how I made the dropdown of available plates shown in the first image.  It will make data entry faster, and you won't have to worry about typos causing an invalid total for that customer.

Comment: YES that is what I want, and the drop down menu is super useful.. for typos and All. Since I am a beginner at excel what I read in your response most of it flew over my head. Its going take me some time to really comprehend what you said haha.